# Rollback the transaction after calling transaction.complete()

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactionscope, msdtc

Is it possible for me to rollback the transaction after calling **scope.complete()** ? Will nested transaction work in this case ? Are there any other alternatives too. I am compelled to add scope.complete in order to call **MyService** correctly. But I want to rollback transaction at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have nested scopes. All scopes must complete for the transaction to complete as well. Scope != transaction.

So the inner scope could complete and the outer scope could rollback. That would rollback the transaction in effect.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not how transactions work.  Once you complete a transaction, that scope is closed and you can't reuse it again elsewhere.  In addition, once a transaction has been completed, it cannot be rolled back.

You'd need to put both transactions in the same scope so that you either can complete them or roll them back together.

Answer (score 1):

The "Durability" part of the ACID properties of Transactions will not allow you to do so.
Transactions one committed cannot be rolled back. 
Instead call the "BillImportProxy.ImportPendingUtilityBills" method from the same transaction scope.